# supremum and infimum

Tags: real-analysis

> If $x \in \mathbb{R}$, prove that $x = \sup \{r \in \mathbb{Q}: r < x \} = \inf \{s \in \mathbb{Q}: x <s \}$.

For convenience, let $A = \{r \in \mathbb{Q}: r < x \}$ and $B = \{s \in \mathbb{Q}: x <s \}$.

I think both of these sets are non-empty by the denseness of the rationals. The elements of $B$ are upper bounds of $A$, and the elements of $A$ are lower bounds of $B$. Hence $\sup A$ and $\inf B$ exist. To actually show that these are equal to $x$, would you suppose $x_1$ was an arbitrary upper bound and show that $x_1 > x$ (similar thing with lower bounds)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that they are not empty is a consequence of the Archimedean property, rather than of the denseness of the rationals (it would be hard to use the denseness of the rationals to establish that both $A$ and $B$ are nonempty  for $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, for example...)

Note that since every element of $A$ is a lower bound for $B$, then $a\leq\mathrm{inf}(B)$ for all $a\in A$; therefore, $\mathrm{inf}(B)$ is an upper bound for $A$, so $\mathrm{sup}(A)\leq\mathrm{inf}(B)$. So you only need to show that they are equal.

Moreover, it is easy to check that $\mathrm{sup}(A)\leq x\leq \mathrm{inf}(B)$.

If you want to proceed by contradiction, one possible way would be to assume that $\mathrm{sup}(A)\lt\mathrm{inf}(B)$. In that case, at least one of $\mathrm{sup}(A)$ and $\mathrm{inf}(B)$ is not equal to $x$. Say $\mathrm{sup}(A)\neq x$; then $\mathrm{sup}(A)\lt x$. Can you come up with some $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ that would satisfy $\mathrm{sup}(A)\lt q\lt x$ in that situation? Then you can try something similar under the assumption that $x\lt \mathrm{inf}(B)$.

Comment: Put $q := (\sup A+x)/2$? So in this case we use the denseness of the rationals?

Comment: @Damien: That $q$ doesn't necessarily work, because you don't whether it is a rational. However, it is indeed a good time to use denseness of the rationals (or the archimedean property again, but denseness will do here).

Comment: @Didier: Thanks!

Comment: For example, $\frac{1+\pi}{2}$ is not rational. Proof: in fact, if $x$ is irrational and $y$ is rational, then $\frac{x+y}{2}$ is irrational. If it were rational, then we could substract the rational number $\frac{y}{2}$ and obtain another rational number; in particular, $\frac{x}{2}$ would be rational. However, this implies that $x$ is rational which is a contradiction. (Hence the average value of a *rational number* and an *irrational number* is *always irrational*.)

Comment: @Arturo: Can I just say that there exists a $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\sup(A) < q < x$ by the denseness of the rationals? Or would I have to explicitly state what $q$ is? So $q$ is not an upper bound but we know that $\sup(A)$ is. Contradiction?

Comment: @Damien: Yes, denseness suffices to guarantee the existence of such a $q$, because we are assuming that the open interval $(\mathrm{sup}(A),x)$ is nonempty, and a dense set intersects every nonempty open set (you might want to say that to justify the existence of $q$); no, you cannot "explicitly state" what $q$ is, because you do not know "explicitly" what $\mathrm{sup}(A)$ is (you are assuming that it is smaller than $x$, but you don't know what it is). The contradiction actually arises because $q\lt x$, $q\in\mathbb{Q}$, so $q\in A$, hence $q\leq\mathrm{sup}(A)$, yet you have $q$ larger.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit different solution:
Wlog we can assume $x>0$ and we only need to show it for the supremum, as $\sup (M)=-\inf(-M)$.
As $x\in \mathbb{R}$ we can express it as a sequence of it's digits.
So $$x=\sum_{k=-m}^\infty a_{k} \cdot 10^{-k},$$
with $a_k\in\{0,1,\dots,9\}$.
Now we define $x_n$ as 
$$x_n=\sum_{k=-m}^n a_{k} \cdot 10^{-k}$$
Obviously $x_n\to x$ so the upper bound is the lowest upper bound and hence the $\sup$